# Storing caret position in editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a content editable div.

I also have a button outside of this div.

When the user presses the button I wish to store the caret position where the user was in the content editable div.

Pressing the button loses focus on the content editable div, so I think the best method would be to store the caret position on blur?

Would there be a more favourable method?

Also, how would I store the caret position for an editable div?

Comment: do you mean "current" or "caret" position?

Comment: yep, just edited my comment as soon as i realized

Comment: what happens when the user clicks on the edit div to restore focus? standard behavior is to place the caret/cursor at the click location, not where it was when focus was lost.

Comment: Marc B - does not matter when the user restores focus, that's not what im asking.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157435/get-last-character-before-caret-position-in-javascript

Comment: In an old project I used to store the caret position on `keyup` and `mouseup`

Comment: [See this](http://akiroom.github.io/caretposition.js/).

Comment: dee - "caretposition.js is useful to measure caret x-y position in textarea." not editable div